# Sequence File created gives strange output in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, sequencefile

I want to combine several small bzip2 files into a sequence file .I saw a code to create sequence file and tried it. But it gives strange output as below. Is this because it is unable to read bzip2 files?

```
SEQorg.apache.hadoop.io.Textorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text  

�*org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec����gWŒ‚ÊO≈îbº¡vœÖ��� ���
    .DS_StorexúÌò±
  ¬0EÔ4.S∫a�6∞¢0P∞=0ì·‡/d)ÄDï˛ì¨w≈ù7÷ùØ›⁄Ã–üO;≥X¬`’∂µóÆ Æâ¡=Ñ   B±lP6Û˛ÜbÅå˜C¢3}ª‘�Lp¥oä"ùËL?jK�&:⁄”Åét¢3]Î
º∑¿˘¸68§ÄÉùø:µ√™*é-¿ﬁﬁ>!~¯·0Ùˆú ¶   eõ¯c‡ÍÉa◊':”ÍÑòù;I1•�∂©���00.json.bz2xúL\gWTK∞%
,Y
ä( HJFêúsŒ\PrRrŒ9ÁCŒ9√0ÃZUÏÌÊΩÔ≤Ù‚Ãô”’UªvÌÍÓ3£oˆä2ä<˝”-”ãÈ§πË/d;u¥Û£üV;ÀÒÛ¯Ú˜ˇ˚…≥2¢5Í0‰˝8M⁄,S¸¢`f•†`O<ëüD£≈tÃ¥ó`•´D˚~aº˝«õ˜v'≠)(F|§ﬁÆÕ ?y¬àœTÒÊYåb…U%E?⁄§eﬁWˇÒY#üÛÓÓ‚
⁄è„ÍåÚÊU5‡  æ‚Â?qÂ‘°�À{©?íWyü÷ÈûF<[˘éŒhãd>x_ÅÁ
ﬁÒ_eâ5-—|-M)˙)¸R·ªCÆßs„F>UŒ©ß{o„uÔ&∫˚˚Ÿ?Ä©ßW,Â”◊Ê∫â«õxã¸[yûgÈñFmx|‡ªÍ¶”¶‡Óp-∆ú§ı
<JN t «F4™@Àä¥Jœ¥‰√|E„‘œ„&º§@g|ˆá{iõOx
```

The code is

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class cinput {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InstantiationException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args)
        .getRemainingArgs();
        Path inputFile = new Path(otherArgs[0]);
        Path outputFile = new Path(otherArgs[1]);
        FSDataInputStream inputStream;
        Text key = new Text();
        Text value = new Text();
        SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs, conf,
                outputFile, key.getClass(), value.getClass());
        FileStatus[] fStatus = fs.listStatus(inputFile);

        for (FileStatus fst : fStatus) {
            String str = "";
            System.out.println("Processing file : " + fst.getPath().getName() + " and the size is : " + fst.getPath().getName().length());
            inputStream = fs.open(fst.getPath());
            key.set(fst.getPath().getName());
            while(inputStream.available()>0) {
                str = str+inputStream.readLine();
               // System.out.println(str);
            }
            value.set(str);
            writer.append(key, value);

        }
        fs.close();
        IOUtils.closeStream(writer);
        System.out.println("SEQUENCE FILE CREATED SUCCESSFULLY........");
    }
}
```

The input I am passing is Json.bzip2 files. Could someone please point out why I am getting strange output.

Comment: Are you using some sort of compression to sequence files? (eg:snappy) Are you reading the file in the first snippet using `cat`?

Comment: how did you get the output of the first block? what happens if you use the `-text` hdfs shell command?

Comment: @Shyam : No. I am not using any compression techniques. This code works fine for Uncompressed input files. But when I give compressed input files, the output is strange.

Comment: @vefthym : even when using -text, I am getting the same output. the code works fine for uncompressed input files but not for compressed input files. Doesn't hadoop automatically decompress bzip2 files?